# Show line in even rows in Reporting service

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report, reporting, ssrs-expression

I have a report that I want add a line beneath the even rows in details section.I add a Line in details section and add this expression to that:

```
=IIF(RowNumber("DataSet1") Mod 2 , "Green", "No Color")
```

but line showed under the last record of my report.my report consist pf a simple table in details section. How I can show a line under even row number records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to display a green line under even-numbered rows in SSRS is to change the Details section row bottom border colour (via the BorderColor:Bottom property in the Proprties Window) to be an expression like the following:

```
=IIF(RowNumber("DataSet1") Mod 2 , Nothing, "Green")
```

(Note that in your original expression the colours were the wrong way around - so that the colour would be set green in odd-numbered rows, not even-numbered - and that "No Color" is not an acceptable colour in SSRS, so you would see warnings when previewing the output in BIDS.)